# Mongodb (nodejsdriver) updateOne query error: MongoError: Either an update or remove=true must be specified

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm currently using mongodb nodejs native driver (MongoDB server version:3.4.1) and I'm using this query:

```
   collection.updateOne(
     { _id : mongodb.ObjectId(data.myId) },
     { $set: { key : data.key } }
   );
```

and I'm receiving this error:

```
(node:12965) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): MongoError: Either an update or remove=true must be specified
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: Yes i've used collection.updateOne it was my fault.

Comment: what was the solution?

Comment: collection.updateOne(
     { _id : mongodb.ObjectId(data.myId) },
     { $set: { key : data.key } }
   );

Comment: sorry if I'm being blind right now, but what's the difference between that and what you posted in your question? looks the same to me.